# How to remove clearcase file using ant

Tags: ant, clearcase

Im writing an ant build script to execute a couple of clearcase commands. Is there ant task to remove a clearcase file(ct rm)? I see there is a ccrmtype task, can this one be used to remove a file?

Thanks,
Aarthi

Answer (score 1):

The list of tasks mentioned at "[Accelerate and automate the build process with IBM Rational ClearCase and Ant](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/tutorials/rantclearcase/section3.html)" and at "[Apache Ant ClearCase Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/clearcase.html)" doesn't include [`cleartool rmname`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmname.htm).

`rmtype` is about removing the *type* (branch or label type for instance), not an *element* (directory or file)

Howevever, looking at the source of [`CCMkelem.java`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid89A246DF1D2CFC58DC65C05908590DD41367A5D0.aspx?s=mcall%3asplit), it wouldn't be hard to implement a `CCRMname`.
It actually exists: **[`CCRmname.java`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid5A2746843AC8CAD3B8020AAE9354AC9D60C57762.aspx?s=mcall%3asplit)**.
So if it isn't present in the latest Ant, take that source, compile it and add it to your ant library.